# Export all hosts from DNS Manager using Powershell

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, export

While I'm rather new to powerShell v3, there's some things I can do with it, however, one thing that has eluded me is how to pull all hosts listed in our DNS Manager (Server 2008 R2). I don't need to set or remove anything just have it query the listing into a text file. Surprisingly I'm not finding a way to do this. Anybody know how to do this, please?

Comment: Why don't you just use dnscmd.exe, it's not PowerShell but it does what you need and can be used in a PowerShell script.

Comment: With 2012, there's a [DsnServer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649850.aspx) module. `Get-DNSResourceRecord -ZoneName ad.mdmarra.local` would dump all records in the domain. One free alternative is the [DnsShell](http://dnsshell.codeplex.com/) module on CodePlex.

Answer (score 6):

I've used DNSShell before.  http://dnsshell.codeplex.com/.  To get all A records in a zone you can do this:

```
Get-DnsRecord -RecordType A -ZoneName FQDN -Server ServerName
```

To get this into a text file:

```
Get-DnsRecord -RecordType A -ZoneName FQDN -Server ServerName | % {Add-Content -Value $_ -Path filename.txt}
```

Answer (score 6):

Another method I don't see mentioned yet:

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace Root\MicrosoftDNS -Query "SELECT * FROM MicrosoftDNS_AType WHERE ContainerName='domain.com'"
```

WMI is good to remember when you can't download DnsShell for some reason, or if you're on an older version of Powershell that doesn't have the baked-in Cmdlets, or if you're targeting an older version of Windows Server.

Answer (score 5):

The DnsServer module available in Windows Server 2012, Powershell v3 has the following commands that might be useful to you:

```
Get-DnsServerZone
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord
```

The first will get you all the zones
The second will get you the records for whatever zone you pass to it

They are basically the equivalent of DNSCMD's `/EnumZones` and `/EnumRecords`.

So... You could write something like this to get ALL of the records from ALL zones:

```
$Zones = @(Get-DnsServerZone)
ForEach ($Zone in $Zones) {
    Write-Host "`n$Zone.ZoneName" -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
    $Zone | Get-DnsServerResourceRecord
}
```

Also, I'm fairly sure that server 2012 keeps an actual zonefile for each zone now? So you should have a file copy for all your zones.

If you're working with 2008 R2, then you can use this script which I use to back up all of my zones to files:

```
$zones = @( `
    dnscmd /enumzones | `
    select-string -pattern "\b(?i)((?=[a-z0-9-]{1,63}\.)(xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,63}\b" | %{$_.Matches} | %{$_.Value};
);

ForEach ($domain in $zones) {
    $backup = "dnscmd . /zoneExport $domain $domain";
    Invoke-Expression $backup | Out-Null
    Write-Host "Backing up $domain" -ForegroundColor "White"
};

ForEach ($item in (gci C:\Windows\System32\dns)) {
    Write-Host "Renaming $item" -ForegroundColor "White"    
Rename-item $item.fullname ([string]$item + ".dns")
}

Write-Host "Back up complete." -ForegroundColor "Cyan"
cmd /c pause | out-null
```